# prove that the next two affirmations are equivalent

Tags: polynomials, roots

prove that the next two affirmations are equivalent :

1) every non constant $f(x)\in \mathbb C[x]$ has all of its roots in $\mathbb C$

2)every non constant $f(x)\in \mathbb C[x]$ has at least one root in $\mathbb C$

the fisrt implication ($1\Rightarrow 2$) is trivial but I don´t know how to prove the second implication ($2\Rightarrow 1$)

I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)$ is polynomial?

Comment: yes! I´ve made the correction

Comment: HINT: If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ and $a$ is a root then $f(z)=(z-a)p(z),$ where $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1.$

Comment: It may be a stupid question but where can be the roots if it's not in $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: The statement 1 should be rephrased as: Every non-constant polynomial splits into linear factors over $\mathbb C$. Otherwise @Fabien's comment is not so stupid at all

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}$ like $z_0$ then $f_1(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x-z_0}\in \mathbb{C}[x]$ too. So $f_1$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}$ like $z_1$. We can construct $f_{i+1}$ from $f_i$ and receive roots $z_i$ and $z_{i+1}$. Since roots of a polynomial are finite then there is $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n$ is constant and $f=f_n (x-z_0)\ldots(x-z_{n-1})$.

Comment: tjanks for the help Hoseyn :D